# wp_title() return value can't be styled

Tags: php, css, wordpress, echo

The title is displayed before my image and is not styled. How to fix it?

```
$tytul = wp_title();
echo '<img class="icon" src="http://site.pl/site/icon.png" /><h2>'.$tytul.'</h2>';
```

Comment: have you used something like firebug or other developer tools to see what styles are at play?

Comment: variable text is displayed just before the image and h2 tags (the are empty)

Comment: Working great on [my side](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OX4qru/55dev?).

Comment: how are you setting `tytul`? And what lines exist above this bit of code?

Comment: the $tytul = wp_title();

Its wordpress function

Comment: Maybe it's because your H2 titles are 'display: block' and have a 'float' setting set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_title()` will print the content itself, not return it, so `echo wp_title()` wont give you anything from the echo, but will print the title. If you use `var_dump(wp_title())`, you will see the title, then the result is `NULL`. What you want is:

```
echo '<img class="icon" src="http://site.pl/site/icon.png" /><h2>';
wp_title();
echo '</h2>';
```