# How to print title in H1 with echo? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, echo

i need to print Title Text in h1, i use it:

```
 <div> if(is_tag()){echo '<h1>' . wp_title('',true,'left') . '</h1>';} </div>
```

But my page prints it out of h1:

```
<div> Title Text <h1></h1> </div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660000/wp-title-return-value-cant-be-styled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter stands for display, you should pass false to return it instead of echoing it

```
<div> if(is_tag()){echo '<h1>' . wp_title('',false,'left') . '</h1>';} </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I did mistake in stackoverflow post, in my code it is opened. So I still cant print it in H1.

Comment: @user3656914 Please **copy-paste** your code exactly as it is to the question. It's impossible to help if you don't show the actual code.

Comment: Juhana, I just did it.

Comment: btw "left" is useless if you don't use any separator (parameter 1)

Comment: Thanks Junius Rendel ;) it was solved after i changed it to "false"